# How do I select specific value from Excel table based on a column and row selection?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like below

I want to create a form where I either select or type in the model from the ones available and then based on that model I want to use an appropriate sX value from the table.

For example, I need value `s7`, for model `A20`.  It is `1.5`.  I want to use that value in another formula.  How do I address that value?

Ideally I want to be able to refer to the value by using the model and the `s7`, rather then the absolute Excel cell location.  Data table is located on a separate sheet, just in case it matters.

[image]

Comment: are you open to vba solution?

Comment: I'd say yes.  But if there is a reasonably simple Excel-only solution available I'd prefer that

Comment: @Gowtham, if you want to post a vba solution I will give you an upvote.  Looking at the amount of computation I'll be doing I am considering going the vba route as well..

Comment: @Dennis I would like to know how you provide the inputs

Comment: In my case, the only input is the model name.  The user will enter it into a cell, such as `B4`.  I also named that cell, `model` using Excel's "Define Name" feature.  Then the code itself will be written to use variables such as `s7`.  Thus, if I need s7 and user selected A20, the code will do something like `result = s7 + 5`, where `s7`'s value depends on what model was chosen by user in the `model` cell.

Comment: @Dennis isnt is supposed to be 2 inputs? model (A20) and the sX value (s7) ?

Comment: true ... but the inputs come from different sources.  A20 is specified by user and is dynamic (and can change).  s7 is specified behind the scenes by hardcoded formulas.   i.e. User wants to see the s7 value for model A20, in cell `F6`.  User selects A20, and the code gives them value of s7 in F6.  Selecting a different A20 will give a different value of s7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX()

```
=INDEX($1:$1048676,MATCH("S7",$A:$A,0),MATCH("A20",$1:$1,0))
```

You can replace the "hard coded" values of `"S7"` and `"A20"` with cell refernces, thus allowing you to put the titles in those cells to return the proper value.

Comment: `$1:$1048676` sets the return range as the full page, the MATCHs return the proper row and column.  In your example, the MATCHS return the 8th row and 3rd column to the full sheet reference thus it returns the value from the 8th row and 3rd column of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks I see that now.  For some reason though the formula returns the value of the cell above s7, in this case `s6`... I'm trying to troubleshoot as to why that's happening.  Adjusting that first value to `B2:N100` seems to give me what I want.  But `$1:$1048676`, gives me unexpected results.

Comment: mm okay I think I got it now .. not sure why it was giving me issues... thanks!

Comment: If you do not use a full sheet reference for the INDEX, you cannot use full column and row references in MATCH(): `=INDEX(B2:N100,MATCH("S7",A2:A100,0),MATCH("A20",B1:N1,0))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which accepts the Model and the sX value to give you the output from the table,

```
Sub searchTable()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
sx = InputBox("Enter sX value")
Model = InputBox("Enter the model")
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) = sx Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
For j = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Cells(1, j) = Model Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next j
'This is the value that you need, which can be used somewhere in your program
MsgBox Cells(i, j)
End Sub
```